# why cant i use a space in seeds names or signs in my minecraft on my ipod

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

why isn't the space bar working in my PE edition worlds. every time i try to use a space bar the words all become connected and i don't know why it does this. i try pressing the space bar a lot and all it does is take away the last letter and add a comma please help me

Comment: It's a confirmed bug.

Answer (score 1):

Mojang has confirmed that this is a bug, you will have to live with it until they patch it